# How do I open Flutter DevTools in a separate window in VSC?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter-devtools

How to open Flutter DevTools in a separate window when using Visual Studio Code, so one can debug on a second monitor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, go to VS Code settings (`ctrl` + `,`) and type `embed devtools`:
[image: VSC settings screenshot]

Unchecking this will result in DevTools being opened in Chrome.

Comment: The name of the setting changed to "Dev Tools Location" and the desired option is "external".

Answer (score 2):

This option would accomplish that.

```
"dart.devToolsLocation": "external"
```